# Azure web app, reading files from wwwroot path

Tags: php, azure, web-applications

First I am newbie working this azure webapps, and I have found this service in partiucular behaves different from a virtual or local server, obviously. I have a php application that loads a pdf file under the wwwroot inside a folder the application does it neatly and we use the following php script:

```
$name= $_FILES['archivocontrato']['name'];'''
$tmppath= $_FILES['archivocontrato']['tmp_name'];'''
$rootfolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];'''
$fullpath=  $rootfolder."/pdf/".$namce;
copy($tmppath,$fullpath);
echo 'File succesfully saved to forlder!'
```

this part does work and it loads the file and the file gets saved under the directory that is being provided.

However when we try to access it, and to open it via an html element anchor . When we try the click, we get error 404 no found. The following script is being used:

```
 $rootfolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 $fullpath=  $rootfolder."/pdf/contratos/"; 
 $actionButton = '<a href="'.$fullpath'.$row['nombre_archivo']." class="btn btn-dark" target="_blank"  ContentType = "application/pdf" role="button"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> Ver Desc</a>';
  $output['data'][] = array(
    $row['Id'],
    $row['Title'],
    $row['Description'],
    $row['fileName'],
    $actionButton
  );
```

Why is it done this way, because we use it to populate a table with the list of the pd files. Now both scrip run smoothly on development enviroment no hassle. However when we publish the php application to azure-web-site app and we clic on that anchor we error 404.

Can someone explain if this can be done this way exactly. because let's say there is no budget for storage nor a blob storage it has to be done this way within the aplication forlders. Do we need to configure something else? Do we use something else like another html element?

Comment: a hyperlink needs to contain a valid URL, not a filesystem path. What is `$fullpath'.$row['nombre_archivo']` actually outputting into the link?

Comment: https://phpapp.azurewebsites.net/home/site/wwwroot/pdf/file.pdf

Comment: @ADyson https://phpapp.azurewebsite.net/home/site/wwwroot/pdf/file.pdf

Comment: I'd assume that it ought to say something like `https://phpapp.azurewebsite.net/pdf/file.pdf` ? I doubt `/home/site/wwwroot` are paths inside the web root - it surely starts at wwwroot?

Comment: sorry I could not unformat the url. Anyhow, yes that is actual path and the file got copied into that directory y checked via ssh on the web app feature and the file is there, I got that path while debuggin the content of the variables just to verify where it was landing, but now I am wondering. In development we use XAMPP and php runs in apache server now this new engine for the linux web apps the **nginx** could it be it is somehow interfering whith the read, however the copying the works fine. I am clueless. Could it be previleges to access those folders and files?

Comment: @ADyson please view my preview comment.

Comment: `Could it be previleges`...no. that would cause a 403 (Fordidden) response, if the webserver couldn't read the file on disk. But you were getting a 404 (Not Found) which means the webserver can't map that URL to any resource within its configured root folder

Answer (score 1):

I made it work aparently we do not need the full path, we shoul always asumme we are at wwwrooot. Basicaly I dropped everything, but the /pdf/ as directory along with the name of the file and presto!

Comment: `we do not need the full path, we shoul always asumme we are at wwwrooot`...yes, because like I said, in a hyperlink you must use a **URL**, not a file path. It has to be something that the webserver can map to a resource via HTTP, and in your case the root of the webserver's configured area is at wwwroot